VIVE Wave SDK: Eye Tracking API does not give useful data
I am developing a game in Unity and trying to replicate the eye tracking feature I've seen in this video.
I am using a VIVE Focus 3 with the Eye Tracking Module and entering Unity Play Mode via VIVE Business Streaming and SteamVR. I am using the VIVE Wave XR Plugin. Here's the documentation about implementing the Eye Tracking. My problem is that I apparently don't get proper Eye Tracking data.
First of, my code looks like this:
if (leftEye != null) 
        {
            //get the position of the RaycastOrigin GameObject to determine where the Ray starts
            Vector3 raycastOrigin = RayCastOrigin.position;
            Vector3 gazeDirection;
            Debug.Log("Is EyeTrackingAvailable"+ eyeManager.IsEyeTrackingAvailable());
            //eyeManager GO gives gaze dir of left eye and stores it as Vector3 Format in gazeDirection var
            if (eyeManager.GetLeftEyeDirectionNormalized(out gazeDirection))
            {
                Debug.Log("Left Eye Direction: " + gazeDirection.ToString())
            ...;

Although I actually get Eye Tracking data, looking at my console reveals I only get 4 different values for the eyes direction.
Console Log shows that 3 directions are given on 2000 frames each
Weird thing is also that I get this data entering playmode even if my VR Headset is not turned on and the data i get looks rather simulated, which is odd as well.
Any guesses on what might be the problem?
I've also tried using Wave.OpenXR.InputDeviceEye.GetLeftEyeDirection without any success.
I cannot see anything off in the project setting as well.
